# Is it possible to delete session outside Flask app?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, session

I have two apps which are both launched by `Flask`. `app1` is port 5000 and `app2` is port 5001.

In my session, I have a key called `username`. I can delete session in `app1` by hitting `http://localhost:5000/delete_session`

```
from flask import Flask

app1 = Flask(__name__)

@app1.get('/delete_session')
def delete_session():
    print(session.keys())  # print is: dict_keys(['username'])
    if "username" in session.keys():
        session.pop("username")
    return "Session clear"

@app1.post('/delete_session')
def delete_session_by_post():
    print(session.keys())  # print is empty: dict_keys([])
    if "username" in session.keys():
        session.pop("username")
    return "Session clear"
```

However, when I hit `http://localhost:5001/logout`, the session is not deleted. Because the session `app1` get is empty `dict_keys([])`

```
import requests
from flask import Flask

app2 = Flask(__name__)

@app2.get('/logout')
def logout():
    requests.post(url='http://localhost:5000/delete_session')
```

Anyone knows why? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as they are on the same domain, they should be able to share cookies.

The problem is that inside your app2 you are making a request to your app1 using `requests` which is a different client from the one that made a request to your app2/app1, so it doesn't store the same cookie.

One simple way to solve this would be to instead redirect the client to your app1.

```py
from flask import Flask, redirect

app2 = Flask(__name__)


@app2.get("/logout")
def logout():
    redirect("http://localhost:5000/delete_session")
```

Another way, would be to import the function from app1 into your app2 and call it

```py
from flask import Flask, redirect
from my_app import delete_session
app2 = Flask(__name__)


@app2.get("/logout")
def logout():
    delete_session()
```

Another way, would be to store sessions server side, for example a database, so you could read sessions and delete them from there.